# How to call suspending function in class that implements an interface with non-suspending functions in Kotlin/JS

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js

I'm writing a Kotlin Multiplatform library using version 1.9.0-RC, and targeting JVM, Native, and JavaScript.

I want to create a class that implements an interface from a dependency.

```kotlin
// this interface comes from my project's dependency

interface ThirdPartyInterface {
  fun getData(): String
}
```

I want to fetch the result of `getData()` from a REST API, but this is implemented differently per target. As such, I've defined an `expect fun` so the implementation can be different for the JVM, Native, and JS targets.

```kotlin
expect suspend fun platformGetData(): String
```

When I try and use this function, I find that I'm not able to call it because there's [no `runBlocking {}` implementation available in commonMain](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/195).

I'm also not able to use `GlobalScope`, because I don't just need to launch a suspending function, I also need to get the result.

```kotlin
// src/commonMain/kotlin/MyCommonClass.kt

import x.y.z.ThirdPartyInterface

class MyCommonClass : ThirdPartyInterface {

  override fun getData(): String {
    // can't use runBlocking, it's not available in commonMain
    // return runBlocking { platformGetData() }

    // I can use GlobalScope() to call the suspend fun...
    val result = GlobalScope().async { platformGetData() }
    // but then I can't read the result!
    result.await() // ERROR Suspend function 'await' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function
  }
}
```

Is there any way to work around this Kotlin/JS restriction?

While a multiplatform equivalent to `runBlocking {}` would work, I understand that this is not possible https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-29403.

I’m not necessarily looking for an equivalent to `runBlocking {}`, but even if there’s a JS-specific function that can bridge blocking/non-blocking then I could change the `expect fun`

```kotlin
//expect suspend fun getData(): String
expect fun getData(): String
```

and then in the `actual fun` use `runBlocking {}` on JVM/Native, and something else on JS.

I don’t mind if the Kotlin/JS code is limited by the inherently single threaded nature of JavaScript - just so long as I can write my code in commonMain, and bridge blocking/non-blocking however is practical for each target.

Comment: I may be entirely wrong, but I believe this is not possible, even conceptually. JavaScript running in the browser can't wait for I/O inside a function (?). That means implementing of `getData()` is not possible in JS, no matter if using Kotlin and coroutines or not.